# Process data in spark and save the result

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-zeppelin

I have three tables with data 2Gb  each one.

1. DC - First table contains data of people (name, genere, passport, etc..).
2. EC - Second table contains addresses of this people.
3. ECK - The third table contains addresses of bills of this people.

I need iterate the second table and search by passport in the third table for generate a score for the best address (multiple algorithms).

How can work with this data and save the result in a table ?

**Note: I'm working with parquet files**

---

***Update (@cheseaux): I have done so far***

I have 3 files: DC.txt, EC.txt and ECK.txt

Import data:

```
val DC = sqlContext.read
          .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
          .option("header", "false")
          .option("inferSchema", "false")
          .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
          .option("delimiter", "|")
          .load("/DC.txt")
```

and save to hive context:

```
DC.select("*").write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("inferSchema", "false")
    .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .option("quote", " ")
    .save("hdfs://localhost:8020/project/DC")
```

create an external table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE EC(
        some     String, 
        var   String, 
        here     String
    )
ROW FORMAT
DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION 'hdfs://localhost:8020/project/DC'
```

and create a parquet table:

```
CREATE TABLE 
    EC_PARQUET(
        some     String, 
        var   String, 
        here     String
  )
ROW FORMAT
    SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS
    INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
    OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
```

Insert all data to parquet table:

```
INSERT INTO EC_PARQUET SELECT * FROM EC
```

Now i'm trying work with this data:

```
val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val ec = hc.sql("SELECT * FROM EC_PARQUET")
```

And trying:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

val test = ec.take(100000).map(row => {
    val row1 = row.getAs[String](1)
    val make = if (row1.toLowerCase == "cualquiercosa") "S" else row1
    Row(row(0),make,row(3))
  }).registerTempTable("teste2")
```

How can create a table with this modification columns ?

Comment: What's your approach so far ? Can you share some code you wrote with us ?

Comment: @cheseaux, i update the post !